ידיים or ידים which is correct
Seen on a Keli with the spelling ידיים. Thinking it might be Sephardi spelling but checked on sefaria Edut Mizrachi and the word was spelled ידים.
Would like to know if there is a difference between the two.

Seems like a modern Hebrew thing.

In Masechet Yadaim, the word is spelled ידים, and in modern Hebrew its spelled ידיים, there is no difference really but it could have to do with the nekudot under the yud
